# Why free GPU is not utilisable?

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I run a deep learning program in PyTorch using `nn.DataParallel`. Since I have eight GPUs available. I am passing `device_ids=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`.

My program runs on the first seven GPUs [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] but not on the last GPU, whose index is 7.

I have no clue on the reason for the same. What can be the possible reason for the non-utilization of the GPU even though it is free to use?

Comment: It is being used for something else?

Comment: @ScottHunter No. It is idle.

Comment: @hanugm I am not sure this question is on-topic here: it seems to be a HW / SW configuration question, not a programming question. Please clarify (by updating the question with this information) what GPUs these are. Specifically, are they all the same model? Are they all attached to the system in the same manner (e.g. each is in one of eight identically configured PCIe4 x4 slots)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nn-dataparallel-doesnt-automatically-use-all-gpus/55467/9)

I am using the batch size of 7. So it is using only 7 GPUs, and if I change it to eight, it is using all the GPUs.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason for this.